# DNSmasq error: dnsmasq[1122]: Too few arguments

Tags: dhcp

DNSmasq status shows  on Raspberry pi 4:

```
Jan 18 17:05:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Jan 18 17:05:13 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1112]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Jan 18 17:05:13 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1121]: started, version 2.80 cachesize 150
Jan 18 17:05:13 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1121]: DNS service limited to local subnets
Jan 18 17:05:13 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1121]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
Jan 18 17:05:13 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[1121]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.0.100 -- 192.168.0.130, lease time 12h
Jan 18 17:05:13 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1121]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
Jan 18 17:05:13 raspberrypi dnsmasq[1122]: Too few arguments.
Jan 18 17:05:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

I am following the DNSmasq set up [here](https://carpie.net/articles/setting-up-a-home-network-dhcp-dns-server-with-dnsmasq). Nslookup and ping by host name on all the Windows and Linux clients suggest local DNSmasq nameservice is working.

The  after <dnsmasq[1121]: read /etc/hosts> suggests a hosts file problem but it is just this :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   raspberrypi
```

No changes were made to dnsmasq.conf. The only by default un-commented lines in it are :

```
hcp-mac=set:client_is_a_pi,B8:27:EB:*:*:*
dhcp-reply-delay=tag:client_is_a_pi,2
```

DNSmasq site specific commands are in /etc/dnsmasq.d/home.dns :

```
# General Configuration
domain-needed
bogus-priv
domain=xyz
dhcp-range=192.168.0.100,192.168.0.130,12h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.0.1
#
# Static IP Assignments
dhcp-host=90:A4:DE:8A:08:86,Onkyo,192.168.0.121
dhcp-host=D4:85:64:A8:EA:04,Manila,192.168.0.122
```

What might the too few arguments error be pointing at?

Comment: the last line says `Started dnsmasq` so, it's running - by the way I get the same error on all my pi's and I've made even less additions than you :p

Comment: The actual issue is something to do when `openresolv` is installed (which seems to be default on Raspberry Pi OS) - I have several servers all running debian, i.e. what Raspberry Pi OS is based on - and none of them have this "error" with dnsmasq - until I install openresolv

Comment: I see that openresolv can be uninstalled - but I don't know what I would be breaking.

Comment: when you uninstall openresolv, you can copy /etc/resolv.conf/bak to /etc/resolv.conf - if the former exists - otherwise, you just edit `/etc/resolv.conf` with entries appropriate to your needs - e.g. I have google nameserver entries in mine `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` - though on the pi, I also have `nameserver 192.168.23.1` before the google ones - where 192.168.23.1 is my router address

Comment: What is the specific problem? I can't see any error message. The message you are worry about isn't marked as error. dnsmasq has exit status 0 (ok).

Comment: I know it wasn't flagged an error but it was suspicious. Too few arguments suggests a command failure. But I defer to those with more experience.

Comment: In /etc/default/dnsmasq there is: #IGNORE_RESOLVCONF=yes     Comments say if resolvconf is installed then dnsmasq will use its output and not /etc/resolv.conf. Since resolvconf is not needed for dnsmasq function can I uncomment it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Too few arguments is not a problem and can be ignored.